# Node Api rest - change database dynamically|

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, express

Is it possible to change the pool config database?

I have a rest API with node/express, and I have multiple databases.
So I need that when a `user.company` login in my frontend, the API rest, choose the database that user should use.

My configuration file for the bank is this `.env`

```
JWT_KEY=XXXXXXX 

POOL1_USER=root
POOL1_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
POOL1_DATABASE=data1  
POOL1_HOST=host.domain.com  
POOL1_PORT=3306
```

Meu arquivo `db.js` é este:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const pool1 = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  user: process.env.POOL1_USER,
  password: process.env.POOL1_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.POOL1_DATABASE,
  host: process.env.POOL1_HOST,
  port: process.env.POOL1_PORT,
});


module.exports = { pool1 };
```

Is this my `controllers.js` file?

```
const mysql = require("../db").pool1;

exports.adminGroup = (req, res, next) => {
  mysql.getConnection((error, conn) => {
    if (error) {
      return res.status(500).send({ error: error });
    }
    conn.query(
      "INSERT INTO adminGroup SET ?",
      [req.body],
      (error, results) => {
        conn.release();
        if (error) {
          return res.status(500).send({ error: error });
        }
        response = {
          mensagem: "Group add",
          grupoCriado: {
            id: results.insertId,
            grupo: req.body.group,
          },
        };
        return res.status(201).send(response);
      }
    );
  });
};
```

I need to dynamically change the database, as I have the same frontend for the same rest API, but I have multiple databases that can even be on different hosts.

It may be that what I'm trying to implement is not possible, so does anyone have any different suggestions?

Comment: DBs hosted on different hosts (well, instances) require a separate connection pool. If the databases are hosted on the same mysql instance, then you can simply use dbname.tablename syntax to access tables in different databases.

Comment: I understood. there are two situations that I have in my structure, and you guys showed me solutions for them, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Before you use the query to select a table from a database, you need to switch the database,  use this query to achieve that.

```
con.query("USE your_db_name", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
```

then after it use the query that you want like this

```
const mysql = require("../db").pool1;

exports.adminGroup = (req, res, next) => {
  mysql.getConnection((error, conn) => {
    if (error) {
      return res.status(500).send({ error: error });
    }
con.query("USE your_db_name", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
      });
    conn.query(
      "INSERT INTO adminGroup SET ?",
      [req.body],
      (error, results) => {
        conn.release();
        if (error) {
          return res.status(500).send({ error: error });
        }
        response = {
          mensagem: "Group add",
          grupoCriado: {
            id: results.insertId,
            grupo: req.body.group,
          },
        };
        return res.status(201).send(response);
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: If the db is on a different host, then "use dbname" is not enough to change the database. The question hints at different dbs being on different hosts.